# batch to run php file from command prompt

Tags: php, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to get a .bat to do the following in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\user1>z:

Z:\>cd "dir1"

Z:\dir1>cd "dir2"

Z:\dir1\dir2>c:\php\php boomi.php boomi
```

Comment: yes - a bat file is just a list of commands. Put the same commands you put on command line into a textfile named `<some name>.bat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not only:

`c:\php\php Z:\dir1\dir2\boomi.php boomi`

Comment: It doesn't seem to like 'boomi' when trying to run via .bat it runs fine if manually entered. Any ideas? message: 'BOOMI' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: what's the output of `c:\php\php` ?

Comment: Managed to get it working using cmd.exe /K "cd /d Z:\dir1\dir2 && c:\php\php boomi.php boomi" the issue was the directory name, when I changed that it worked - thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.exe /K "cd /d Z:\dir1\dir2 && c:\php\php boomi.php boomi
```

did what I needed to do, I had to change a directory name as it kept throwing up and error.